(Micro-) Python callback function inside class throws type error
I'm more or less new to Python and still struggling a bit with OOP (coming from C - not C++).
I want reuse and extend a rotary encoder class and just wanted to add a switch with an interrupt callback routine. But it always throws an error:
from rotary_encoder.rotary_irq_esp import RotaryIRQ
from machine import Pin



class RotaryEncoder(RotaryIRQ):
  # rotary options
  RANGE_MODE = const(1) # 1->UNBOUNDED, 2->WRAP, 3->BOUNDED
  PIN_CLK = const(7)
  PIN_DT = const(8)
  PULL_UP = True

  # switch options
  PIN_SWITCH = const(6)
  PULL_UP_SWITCH = True
  
  def __init__(self, pin_num_clk=PIN_CLK, pin_num_dt=PIN_DT, min_val=0, max_val=10, incr=1,range_mode=RANGE_MODE, pull_up=PULL_UP,pin_switch=PIN_SWITCH,pull_up_switch=PULL_UP_SWITCH):
    super().__init__(pin_num_clk, pin_num_dt, min_val, max_val, incr, range_mode, pull_up)
    # add switch
    if pull_up_switch:
      self.switch = Pin(pin_switch,Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
      self.switch.irq(trigger=Pin.IRQ_FALLING, handler=self._rotary_switch_callback)
    else:
      self.switch = Pin(pin_switch,Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
      self.switch.irq(trigger=Pin.IRQ_RISING, handler=self._rotary_switch_callback)

  def _rotary_switch_callback(self):
    pass

Do you have any idea why it's not working??
The error is:
TypeError: function takes 1 positional arguments but 2 were given
I tried several things but nothing worked.
In another component I saw a callback function definition inside a class without (self) argument. This will also not work here (and by the way confuses me a lot why a function inside a class which is not a static method or class method is there without a (self) argument - but this is another topic :-)
I tried
handler=self._rotary_switch_callback)
handler=_rotary_switch_callback)

def _rotary_switch_callback(self):
def _rotary_switch_callback():


If I use the code outside a class it works but an additional argument is the instance itself. No idea how I should transfer this into the class.
def rotary_switch_callback(rotary_switch):
   pass 
rotary_switch = Pin(6,Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
rotary_switch.irq(trigger=Pin.IRQ_FALLING, handler=rotary_switch_callback)

If I do the following it (of course) does not work :-)
self.switch = Pin(pin_switch,Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
self.switch.irq(trigger=Pin.IRQ_RISING, handler=self._rotary_switch_callback)

def _rotary_switch_callback(self, self.switch):
  pass

I have no real idea why it does not work but I think I can't give an instance.instance as argument if the instance itself is the argument. Any idea how I can solve this the "correct" way without ugly tricks?

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

what is self.switch.irq? It may run your function with some value(s) - self._rotary_switch_callback(some_value1) - and you have to get them - def _rotary_switch_callback(self, parameter):. If you don't know if it will be executed with some argumens then you can use *args, **kwargs to catch all.

According to the MicroPython documentation:
handler is an optional function to be called when the interrupt triggers. The handler must take exactly one argument which is the Pin instance.

This means the handler function must accept one argument, which will be the Pin instance that triggered the interrupt.
When you set up an interrupt like this:
self.switch.irq(trigger=Pin.IRQ_RISING, handler=self._rotary_switch_callback)

the handler function is expected to take two arguments: self and the Pin instance. (The self argument is implicit in instance methods.)
So, you need to modify your _rotary_switch_callback method to accept the Pin instance as a parameter:
def _rotary_switch_callback(self, pin):
    pass


I don't know what is self.switch.irq() but it seems it executes your function with some extra parameters - e.g PIN - and you have to get it
def _rotary_switch_callback(self, parameter):

If you don't know how many parameters it will send and you don't know if it will positional arguments or named arguments then you can use popular *args, **kwargs
def _rotary_switch_callback(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print('args:', args)
    print('kwargs:', kwargs)

But you should have information about parameters in documentation.

You are right. I extended my description. Sorry for being not exact.

*args worked ... but why ??? :-)

The print shows (Pin(6),) - so in my world the second argument is still empty. No idea why it works no. I know that *args allows multiple arguments. But I don't give any additional argument so what's exactly going on here?
BTW thanks a lot for solving my problem :-) - but the mystery grows bigger now :-D

no, your first argument is self, your second argument is Pin(6). This function gets handler=self._rotary_switch_callback and later it runs handler(Pin(6)) which gives self._rotary_switch_callback(Pin(6)) but Python threads it as RotaryEncoder._rotary_switch_callback(self, Pin(6)). The same is in C++ - when you run object.func(args) then it runs ClassName.func(object, args) or even it runs normal function in C code classname_func(object, args)
